# Regex remove everything after last occasion of semicolon

Tags: regex

i have for example this string:

> hello; how; are; you; ?

and i need to delete everything after last occasion of semicolon. I know that it is easy but i haven't a lot of time to learn regular expressions.  Im using text editor PSPad which supports regular expressions functions and the text is in simple txt file.

Thank you

Comment: -1 which laguage..where are u using this regex..what kind of text editor..can u be more open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which language you want this in, but in PHP, this works:

PHP

```
$string = 'hello; how; are; you; ?';
$string = preg_replace('#[^;]*$#', '', $string);
```

Perl

```
my $string = 'hello; how; are; you; ?';
$string =~ s/[^;]*$//;
```

Comment: Text editors may use a perl style, so give the perl method I just added a try.